# Custom ListView text always overlays each other

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-listview, android-xml

I have made a card layout for displaying a list of data. For some reason, no matter which properties I change for layout width, height, weight, etc, the text is always shown on top of other lines of text, as shown below.

[image]

What am I missing?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:background="@drawable/card_inset">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/eventDetails"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="70"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/eventTeams"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textSize="17sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/eventClickForMore"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/eventTimeSection"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="30"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/eventTime"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="22sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/eventDate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `TextView` called `eventClickForMore`, add the attribute `android:layout_below="@+id/eventTeams"`.

And do the same thing for the `TextView` called `eventDate` which should be below `eventTime`

**EDIT**

I have updated the code, basically, you need to change the `layout_height` attribute of `eventTeams` and `eventTimeSection` to `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`. `match_parent` made the `TextView` to take all the space vertically.

Also I think you could get rid of `android:layout_alignParentBottom` and `android:layout_alignParentLeft` in `eventClickForMore` and `eventDate` (not sure though, maybe the first update will be enough).

See my code below :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:background="@drawable/card_inset">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/eventDetails"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="70"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/eventTeams"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="17sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/eventClickForMore"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/eventTeams"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/eventTimeSection"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="30"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/eventTime"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="22sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/eventDate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/eventTime"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: you should not put `+` in your `layout_below`

Comment: As noted above, I did this (without the + as mentioned in the comments above) and it actually seems to hide the eventClickForMore and eventDate sections. They are not visible at all.

Comment: I have updated my post, let me know if you still face the problem!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `android:layout_below` in your `TextView` with `id` `@+id/eventClickForMore`,

see

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/eventClickForMore"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below = "@id/eventTeams"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:textSize="14sp" />
```

Comment: Just making that change actually seems to make the eventClickForMore disappear all together. Is there another existing property that would conflict with that? I have made no other changes.